# How to typeset numbering of problems as in "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves"

Tags: numbering, chapters

I would like to typeset solutions to a book in algebraic geometry. Namely, the author numbers the chapters like in

```
1 Some topics in commutative algebra
1.1 Tensor products
1.1.1 Tensor product of modules
1.1.2 Right exactness of tensor products
1.1.3 Tensor product of algebras
```

and then there are problems 1.1.1 to 1.1.7, namely under the caption Tensor products. Then there is

```
1.2. Flatness
1.2.1-1.2.3 Some smaller subsections
```

and then there are problems 1.2.1 to 1.2.19.

and so on

So how can I do the enumeration to the solution manual for my own use, such that I can easily type the problems in flatness like

```
1.2.7. Give an example of a finitely generated flat module that is not free (over a suitable ring).

Solution ...

1.2.8. Show that ...

Proof ...
```

It should not number those problems under the subsection 1.2.3 but under the section 1.2.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'm sorry, maybe it's just me, but I don't quite understand what do you want. What's wrong with `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`?

Comment: Do you want to write something like `Exercise 1.1.7` and `Solution 1.1.7` followed by text?

Comment: I was hoping more like `Exercise 1.1.6`, `Solution`, `Exercise 1.1.7`, `Solution` because my style to write is that the solution corresponds the problem above, i.e. there is no problems inside solutions. The word `Exercise` is not necessary.

Comment: I tried `\section{Some topics in commutative algebra} \subsection{Tensor product} \begin{problem}Let ...\end{problem}` but it enumerates problems like 1. Let ... and not like 1.1.1. Let ...

Comment: Tag the user you want to address with `@` (like @selflearner) and they will be notified. Now, could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help us reproduce what you are doing? `:)`